# App Insights - Empty as zeros

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

When I use `bin(timestamp, 1m)` and generate a timechart of it, null values generate a straight line. How can i treat missing values as zeros?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use the make-series operator instead of summarize, with default=0.

[Make-series documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator)

make-series creates a series that can be analyzed using advanced time-series functions. It's a bit clunkier than summarize, but offers other advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `iif()` in conjnction with an `isnull()` or `isempty()`. Mind you if your pulling from a custom metric you will need to make sure you're value is set to the same type.

`requests
| extend mycustomvalue = toint(todynamic(customDimension).customDuration)
| extend mycustomduration = iif((isnull(mycustomvalue) or isempty(mycustomvalue)), 0.0, mycustomvalue)`

Comment: that only exists if you have rows. if you have gaps in time where there are no requests, this still returns no rows.  `make-series` is probably the better answer if you're doing a timechart and there might be gaps.